# How do I use a non-final variable in a Android View's onClickListener?

Tags: android

I got some problems with some of my code. Basiclly, it's a countdown program, but whenever a button is clicked, it should refresh the countdown.
I hope that makes sense. Below is some of my code, however, it's not working as intended.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    final Button refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final int j = 30000;
    int i = j;
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            j = 30000;
        }
    });

     new CountDownTimer(i, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();
}
```

My problem is, that I need to make a variable final to access it in a onClickListener, but I can't change it once it's final.


Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm ... local inner classes can only access the final local variables !

Comment: You can use an instance variable if possible .

Comment: @Akash : static is not necesary.

Comment: anyway, simply reseting the value of j is not sufficient. you also need to make a new countdowntimer with the new value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make j a field variable and don't make it final, that will solve your problem

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   int j;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    final Button refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    j = 3000;
    int i = j;
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        j = 30000;
    }
});

 new CountDownTimer(i, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is just make `j` a member variable then you can use it anywhere in the class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int j = 3000;  // declare it here as a member variable
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
    final Button refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

This way you don't have to make it `final`.